# How to solve Retrofit 2 inner Json converting issues?

Tags: android, json, type-conversion, retrofit, retrofit2

My issue is related the JSON file itself.

My Retrofit instance :

```
@Provides
@Singleton
fun provideRetrofit(client: OkHttpClient): Retrofit {
    return Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl("some url")
        .client(client)
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .build()
}
```

I tried to get the json object response like below:

```
@GET("items/{id}?")
suspend fun getItemById(@Path("id") itemId: String): JsonObject
```

butI got the error :

```
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at path $.images[0]
```

I figured that JSON converter found problems while parsing the code below :

```
{
  "id": "1",
  "title": "some text",
  "images" : [
    "https://url_{imageId}.jpeg",
    "https://url_{imageId}.jpeg",
    "https://url_{imageId}.jpeg"
   ]
}
```

I think it is related to the part "{imageId}" founded in the url String which is I found strange and what more stranger is that the error occurs even before I try parsing it to its relatif POJO.

My POJO class is :

```
data class Item (
  val id : String?,
  val title : String?,
  val images : List<String> = emptyList()
)
```

Any idea ?

Comment: definition return type with prop images: List<String>.

Comment: Share POJO class

Comment: @Praveen I updated the description, you can check.